# 'altinstall' python-devel; can't install psycopg2 on centos

Tags: centos, python, pip

I installed python2.7 on my

```
centos 2.6.32-431.17.1.el6.x86_64
```

following these directions:

http://toomuchdata.com/2014/02/16/how-to-install-python-on-centos/

```
#after the yum stuff...
# Python 2.7.6:
wget http://python.org/ftp/python/2.7.6/Python-2.7.6.tar.xz
tar xf Python-2.7.6.tar.xz
cd Python-2.7.6
./configure --prefix=/usr/local --enable-unicode=ucs4 --enable-shared LDFLAGS="-Wl,-rpath /usr/local/lib"
make && make altinstall
```

I am trying to install  psycopg2:

```
[stuff]# pip2.7 install psycopg2
...
./psycopg/psycopg.h:31:22: error: libpq-fe.h: No such file or directory
```

Upon researching, that means I need to install python-devel (I think), but I can't install this because it would install for my 2.6 default on the system.

I tried to install from source:

```
[stuff]# python2.7  ./external_dependancies/psycopg2-2.5.3/setup.py install
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./external_dependancies/psycopg2-2.5.3/setup.py", line 474, in <module>
    use_pydatetime  = int(parser.get('build_ext', 'use_pydatetime'))
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/ConfigParser.py", line 607, in get
    raise NoSectionError(section)
ConfigParser.NoSectionError: No section: 'build_ext'
```

**What do I need to do to get python-devel (or better yet, psycopg2) on my system**

Comment: why not using pip and virtualenv to install a specific version of python in a directory?

Comment: I'd still need the python-devel, right? Isn't that a system package, not a python environment package?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was missing this package:

```
libpqxx-devel.x86_64
```